# Zend Framework 2 - Multiple sub domains cause problems

Tags: subdomain, url-routing, zend-framework2

I am writing an application in Zend Framework 2 which is going to run from a few different subdomain, and I want to have a different module for each sub domain, to keep things tidy.

My problem is when I add more than 1 sub domain to the routing, it loses one of the sub domains.

eg: This setup works 
testbed.localhost (module/Application)
a.testbed.localhost (module/A)

If I add an extra one it will the route all requests for a to the Application Index Controller

eg
testbed.localhost (module/Application), a.testbed.localhost (module/A), b.testbed.localhost (module/B)

This is the module.config.php for module/A

```
    'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'ads' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                 'route'    => 'a.testbed.localhost', 
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'A\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'A\Controller\A',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
```

And this is the route in module.config.php in module/B

```
    'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'ads' => array(
            'type'    => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                 'route'    => 'b.testbed.localhost', 
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'B\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'B\Controller\B',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
```

Now the namespaces are correct in both the module.config.php files, what I have noticed is the sub domain a.testbed.localhost will work if I remove the reference to it from config/application.config.php

```
    <?php
    return array(
        'modules' => array(
         'Application',
         'A',
         'B', <--- A doesn't work if B is here
      ),
```

And if I swap A & B around in the modules array above, then B will get forwarded to the Application Module and A will work. So it seems to have problems with more than 1 sub domain. Has anyone got any ideas / come across the same thing?

Comment: I *think* it's because your route names are the same. Maybe try a-ads and b-ads for route names and see what happens.

Comment: You're right, jesus I can't believe I didn't spot that. Was staring at that for a few hours yesterday!

Comment: Can you close the question, so it doesn't stay in the unanswered list?

Comment: @Diemuzi, you solved my problem. Write your comment as answer.

Comment: @deadtoy Can you please close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your route names are the same. I would try a-ads and b-ads for route names and that should resolve your situation.

In the end the configuration is getting merged together. So it's like an array, when the last array is merged it overwrites anything before it.